# Audio range with custom waveshape

Tags: i2c, pwm, audio, signal-processing, dac

I am planning to use several Arduino to produce audio range analog signals. I need to use custom waveshapes generated on the fly. As far as I understand, there are two paths:

1. Aquiring a DAC, but can I send instructions fast enough (the Arduino needs to process the waveshape table) for audio rate signals? On a DAC like this [one](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/MCP4725_2009.pdf), I see that it supports a 100kb/s standard I2C and a 12 bit precision, so my guess is I will have `100kb/s / 12b / 10kHz = 0.8 input/period` at 10kHz... Will this suffice? Or will it creates compression artefacts?
2. Using the [Mozzi](https://sensorium.github.io/Mozzi/) library, but it seems to me it outputs through a PWM digital IO pin. As I have a lot of Arduino to process, I would like to limit the number of RC circuitry I have to solder. Moreover, can Mozzi use custom waveshapes?

If you see any other solution, you are very welcome !

Thanks in advance

Comment: and I2S DAC ? .

Comment: Keep in mind the nyquist rate: You need at very least 2 samples per period to make sure the resulting wave has anything to do with the real target wave. And when you want to represent the shape of the wave correctly, then you will need significantly more samples. What is the highest frequency signal part, that you need to represent?

Comment: I need to go up to 20 kHz. I will investigate the I2S path. Thanks !